# RSA encryption library for C++

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, rsa

I am developing a Win32 application and I would like to use an RSA encryption library. **Which library would you recommend?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the following library:

http://www.efgh.com/software/rsa.htm

It's public domain, compact, self contained, and does the work well.

Comment: This library does not use padding. That is a significant omission.

Comment: True that, I did improve it though by adding that. Problem is, I lost the code :(. It wasn't' too difficult to add though...

Comment: It uses 16-bit ints as primitive elements. It's probably fairly slow on modern hardware. Also, if I understand correctly, it uses a naive implementation for the pow/mod operation. Faster algorithms exist...

Answer (score 25):

If you're using Win32, why don't you simply use the built-in win32 crypto-API?

Here's a little example how it works in practice:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/EncryptionCryptoAPI.aspx

Comment: It doesn't appear to be C++ for one.

Comment: The Win API is in C, which is immediately usable within a C++ program.

Comment: Yep. If you favor a C++ interface, write yourself a wrapper around it. May be a good idea anyways just in case you later want to change the API.

Comment: Because that is highly insecure given the fact that nobody trusts Microsoft to encrypt files anymore.

Comment: True. The answer was given before the Snowden/NSA crypto meltdown..

Answer (score 18):

[Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) - They have NIST FIPS validated dll's for MSVC 6, 7.1, and 8 on top of the normal source code self built packages.

Comment: there's no question for me, the NIST seal-of-approval means a lot. Encryption is not one of those things you want to mess around with -- you HAVE to be able to trust that it's implemented correctly & doesn't have security holes.

Answer (score 14):

I think OpenSSL is a good choice.  It's well-maintained, and the price is right :)

http://www.openssl.org

Comment: Do keep in mind that OpenSSL is not GPL compatible.

Comment: It's written in C, and is immediately usable within a C++ program.

Comment: @Leon you can use OpenSSL with a GPL app, it's an explicit FAQ entry. http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#LEGAL2

Comment: @Bruno: From FAQ you linked: "On other systems [other then  Linux/BSD], the situation is less clear. Some GPL software copyright holders claim that you infringe on their rights if you use OpenSSL that don't normally include OpenSSL.". Wikipedia states that OpenSSL is not compatible.

Comment: The FAQ entry is pretty clear, it is definitely compatible on systems where OpenSSL is shipped by default, exactly like a GPL program can link to a proprietary libc on say, AIX. It may be more greyish on other systems, no way to know for sure until a court decision is reached on that.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, consider LibTomCrypt (https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt)

Comment: It's written in C, and is immediately usable within a C++ program.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus: thanks, I've updated to a working link.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) is an alternative? It is a C++ library with a BSD license that supports RSA algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is [libbeecrypt](http://beecrypt.sourceforge.net/). A very mature product with assembler implementations on many platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I have used OpenSSL in past and found it a great library for crypto APIs including AES, RSA, 3DES.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Miracl library https://certivox.com/solutions/miracl-crypto-sdk/ but the price is high.