# Encrypting a string in Java and decrypting it in C++

Tags: java, c++, cryptography, encryption

I need to encrypt a string in Java and decrypt it in C++. I've seen C++ has a Crypto++ library and Java has JCE, Jasypt, BouncyCastle etc. but I'm getting more and more confused...

I'm searching for something simple. High security it's not required for this use case. It's important for the encryption algorithm on one side to be analogous to the one on the other side, configuring them in the simplest way.

---

**EDIT (improved explanation):**

I would like to do this:

- in **Java**: take an **input string**, **encrypt** it with a **string password** (and not other things like byte arrays or initialization vectors), obtaining an **encrypted string**
- in **C++**: receive the above encrypted string and **decrypt** it with the same string password as above, obtaining the original input string

For the Java part I know this Jasypt code:

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor hexEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor() ;
hexEncryptor.setStringOutputType("hexadecimal");
hexEncryptor.setPassword(ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD);
String encryptedString = hexEncryptor.encrypt(inputString);
```

It would be great, but I don't know wich algorithm it uses and what's the analogous in C++ for decrypting it.

Comment: Any industry-standard encryption (AES, etc) can do this. I don't have any code, but maybe it would help others if you explained exactly what problem you're having

Comment: I would use some ssl, jave should have some library and on the c++ side jsut use openssl library.

Comment: @RageZ but encryption is needed not only during the communication: the transmited string must be stored on the C++ (client) side on a file. So I transmit it on a XML document. Client decrypts it whenever it needs.

Comment: @Robert I've tried AES using JCE, but didn't work, so I tried Triple-DES with JCE, but I get confused with output encodings.

Comment: @bluish: I see I suppose then you should use something else, or recrypt the output of openssl.

Comment: I suggest figuring out what the StandardPBEStringEncryptor() is using.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, it's not a ton of work. You just need building blocks from crypto libraries.

1. Use PBKDF1 or PBKDF2 for key derivation. Both algorithms have many implementations in both C++ and Java. You put in a password, you get a symmetric encryption key out.
2. You say "high security is not important", which I don't think makes a ton of sense (you either have security or you don't), but let me latch onto it and take it to mean you'd be content to use a stream cipher such as RC4 instead of AES with its IVs and block cipher modes, etc, which can be a pain to deal with in various implementations.
3. So use RC4 aka ARC4. Again, many implementations in Java and C++. You feed it your key and a string of bytes, and out comes a string of bytes: plaintext or ciphertext, based on the operation. RC4 doesn't have a great reputation but to this day it's the default cipher in IE and IIS for TLS. You're going to be fine with RC4. (I'm not a fan of IE and IIS for a large number of reasons, but RC4 is not on my list.)
4. For good measure you may want to prefix your plaintext before encryption with a header. You can put the length of the plaintext in the header and the SHA1/256/512 (take your pick) hash of the plaintext. Again, many good implementations for these hash algos in C++ and Java. You then encrypt the header as well as the plaintext. This way it's going to be very easy to tell if decryption is gone well; just verify the length and hash fields.

As long as you use the same, well-established algorithms in both C++ and Java, and you have a well-defined interchange format (see 4 above) you can solve this problem quickly and securely.

EDIT:

Note, there are caveats that apply to stream ciphers. Quoting Schneier:

> One of the most important rules of
>   stream ciphers is to never use the
>   same keystream to encrypt two
>   different documents. If someone does,
>   you can break the encryption by XORing
>   the two ciphertext streams together.
>   The keystream drops out, and you end
>   up with plaintext XORed with plaintext
>   -- and you can easily recover the two plaintexts using letter frequency
>   analysis and other basic techniques.
>
> It's an amateur crypto mistake. The
>   easy way to prevent this attack is to
>   use a unique initialization vector
>   (IV) in addition to the key whenever
>   you encrypt a document.

Answer (score 2):

If security is not important, just XOR it on one end with, say, 70, then XOR again on the other. This will take about 10 minutes for any cracker to figure out by hand. Or a grandma who's good at solving the cryptoquotes in the newspaper.

If you really want secure+easy and "slow" doesn't matter (processing <1x per sec on average or 10x/sec if you have the machine to yourself), do this:

1. **implement encrypt/decrypt with a common Java library**
2. **have the C++ do a `process.start` to the Java decryptor**

Pass something unique, say the process ID of the C# program, as a parameter to the Java program, you can share a file that includes that ID. Or if you can make the Java program run as a console program, have it read/write the console and the C# use the `Process.StandardInput`/`StandardOutput`. Or... etc. etc.

Ugly hack, yes. If you want to work fast and complete more work in your day, figure out if your customers or users are going to care.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe it's because "High security it's not required" doesn't imply "Very low security is allowed"

Comment: It's either secure, or it's obfuscated. There's no middle ground. You either put effort into your encryption code to make it bulletproof, or you admit defeat and call your implementation obfuscation.

Comment: I very much agree with your 1st paragraph, in a tounge-in-cheek way. I don't think the rest is practical though.

Comment: @jweyrich, @thejohndonson, @martona: Points well taken. It didn't come to mind at the time, but _obfuscation_ is a word I should have used. And there is no middle ground. For example, For example, all DRM is, in a philosophically foudational sense is just really hotshot obfuscation! Even though it may employ 'secure' stuff like encryption. Why? If it were secure, the content would be inaccessable! Yet it is useful for the case. As regards the impracticality of the solution, again, depends on the case. which is why the OP should _tell us exactly what he's trying to do_, rather than just how._

Comment: @FastAI, +1, the problem with democracy is majority need not be always right. if you succeed cracking you call it obfuscation, if not you maintain it as encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I have researched it a lot in the internet and no solution was found. So I decided to do it by myself.

I have created a class to do that! The below code explain by itself. Good look!

```
            #pragma once
            #include <string>
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/aes.h"
            using namespace CryptoPP;

            //.h

                class CryptoUtil 
                {
                public:
                    CryptoUtil(std::wstring mac);

                    byte m_key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
                    byte m_iv[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
                    char m_macInChar[12];

                    // decripty string encrypted in AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding mode
                    std::wstring DecryptStr(std::wstring str);
                };


            //.cpp
            #include "stdafx.h"
            #include "CryptoUtil.h"
            #include <atlstr.h>
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/cryptlib.h"
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/filters.h"
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/modes.h"
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/modes.h"
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/aes.h"
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/filters.h"
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/aes.h"
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/base64.h"
            #include "../../Include/Cryptopp562/md5.h"


            using namespace CryptoPP;




            CryptoUtil::CryptoUtil(std::wstring mac)
            {
                CryptoPP::MD5 md5;

                byte ivString [] = { "blablabla!@#$&&&&&&&" };

                md5.CalculateDigest(m_iv, (byte*) ivString, 20);

                char macInChar[12 + 1];

                size_t charsConverted = 0;

                wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, macInChar, mac.c_str(), mac.length());

                md5.CalculateDigest(m_key, (byte*) macInChar, 12);
            }

            std::wstring CryptoUtil::DecryptStr(std::wstring str)
            {
                std::string encoded, decoded, recovered;

                //change wchar to char
                size_t outputSize = str.length() + 1;

                char* pBuffer = new char[outputSize];

                size_t charsConverted = 0;

                wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, pBuffer, outputSize, str.c_str(), str.length());

                std::string plain(pBuffer);

                delete [] pBuffer;

                char * pFormattedStr = new char[outputSize];
                int sizeOf = sizeof(pFormattedStr);

                sprintf_s(pFormattedStr, outputSize, "%16s", plain.c_str());

                encoded = pFormattedStr;

                delete [] pFormattedStr;

                try
                {

                    StringSource ss(encoded, true,
                        new CryptoPP::Base64URLDecoder(
                        new StringSink(decoded)
                        ) // Base64URLDecoder
                        ); // StringSource


                    CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption dec;
                    dec.SetKeyWithIV(m_key, sizeof(m_key), m_iv);

                    // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
                    //  padding as required.
                    //StringSource s(cipher, true,
                    StringSource s(decoded, true,
                        new StreamTransformationFilter(dec,
                        new StringSink(recovered)
                        ) // StreamTransformationFilter
                        ); // StringSource


                    CStringW strTemp = CA2W((char*) recovered.c_str(), CP_UTF8);

                    strTemp.Trim();

                    std::wstring strRecovered(strTemp);

                    return strRecovered;

                }
                catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: AES is a block cipher i.e. it encrypts or decrypts blocks of a fixed number of bytes - normally 16. So you need something like AES/CBC oder AES/CTS.

- For C++ I don't know anything else than Crypro++.
- For Java with JCE

Sample:

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.Key;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public static void runEncTest( byte[] encryptionKey, byte[] ivBytes, byte[] input )
{
  try
  {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec( encryptionKey, "AES" );

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( "AES/CTS/NoPadding" );
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);

    printByteArray( "PLAIN:", input );
    printByteArray( "CRYPT:", cipherText );      
  }
  catch( java.lang.Exception e )
  {
    System.out.println("Got an Exception: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: @ur Thanks! what's ivBytes? Moreover I would like my encryption key to be a String, not an array of byte. And the output too: I need to send it inside an xml, so I need a String, I don't know how to send an array of byte.

Comment: @bluish It's the initialization vector. Set it to the same 16 bytes when encrypting and decrypting. You can roll the dices when encrypting and send those 16 bytes as plaintext with the encrypted string to the Java program. Don't use 16 zeroes.

Comment: To get a key from a password you usually put it through a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 and use it's output as the key. To get a byte array from a string you can UTF8 encode the string.

Comment: @sheepsimulator: It's "ciphertext stealing" - a method to encrypt data which doesn't have a length which is a multiple of the (AES) block size. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing

Answer (score 0):

RSA encryption is a public key encryption that is quite easy to implement and use.

There was an earlier post on stackoverflow about RSA encryption in C++: [RSA encryption library for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108518/rsa-encryption-library-for-c).

A quick Google search for Java RSA will provide you with ample libraries to encrypt/decrypt for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Just analyze the ciphers used in C++ and Java. In Java default is ECB. This might be a problem.