# RSA Encryption for C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cryptography

I was working on converting C# code to VC++ (no support for .net). I encountered following line of code.

```
RSA.VerifyData(hash, "SHA1", signature)
```

How to achieve this? Here hash is the encrypted information. Signature is information retrieved from User's end. This function returns a boolean value. Is there any way to perform same verification on char* directly in C++?

Comment: Yes, you need to find a C++ RSA library.

Comment: You're looking for CAPI or CNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [CPVerifySignature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  or [CryptVerifySignature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions - Available in the CryptoAPI (Windows native).

Comment: you might also want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108518/rsa-encryption-library-for-c) question as there are several other libraries proposed... however, it would introduce additional dependencies...

Comment: @xmoex: Since the OP is porting from C# to C++ and was (apparently) using the framework methods, I would recommend for consistency to continue using Microsoft's API (or a wrapper around it).  This may (or may not - consult a lawyer) have a side benefit of reducing concerns oriented around cryptography export law, since it avoids including encryption algorithms in code by calling algorithms which were provided to the user by Microsoft.

Comment: @Brian: for the US this may be true... i'm no expert in US politics regarding cryptography related laws. i see your point in beeing consistent and therefore using microsoft's api, but for the sake of completeness i wanted to point out some alternatives...

Comment: I went thorugh this article... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There very second function CryptGetUserKey is throwing error. From GetLastError() function I can see the error is NT_NO_KEY. Please help :|

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options you can choose from:

- The [WinAPI cryptography features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI). Obviously windows-only, C, and WinAPI-style (I find it painful and counter-intuitive to work with). CAPI is the older one, and CNG is the newer (for Vista a newer). I personally don't suggest this solution, unless you have very special requirements<sup>(1)</sup>.
- [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) provides a wide range of cryptography features, including RSA signature verification. This one is my favorite, it has a nice model of message pipes and filters which allows for using multiple algorithms on the data with ease. The API is a bit procedural (there is essentially a begin_message and end_message call enclosing the actual writing of data), but I found it intuitive and easy to understand (this is, of course just an opinion).
- [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) has a different style of API. I found it less intuitive and I always choose Botan over this library. The API seems more orthodox, but less straightforward. It doesn't seem any less capable than Botan, and many people indeed recommend it.

---

<sup>(1) if you need a library that is reviewed by a third-party (for very serious use-cases, like bank software for example), you might want to choose CAPI after all, because it allows you to use a third-party reviewed [Cryptography Service Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Service_Provider).</sup>